# Don't Understand SQL Procedure Error

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a master table "Repairs" and a detail table "RepairDetails"  I am trying to write a procedure to update both tables when I send the appropriate parameters from my application.  Here is my SQL:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateRepair]
    @RepairID bigint,
    @TypeID bigint = NULL,
    @Directions nvarchar(3000) = NULL,
    @NewDetails NewDetails READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE Repairs
    SET
        TypeID = ISNULL(@TypeID, TypeID),
        Directions = ISNULL(@Directions, Directions),
        LastUpdate = SYSDATETIME()
    WHERE RepairID = @RepairID;
    IF @NewDetails IS NOT NULL UpdateRepairDetails;
END
```

where "NewDetails" is a User-defined table type and "UpdateRepairDetails" is a different stored procedure that takes @RepairID and @NewDetails as parameters.

I have an error and a question.  The error message is:

```
Must declare the scalar variable "@NewDetails"
```

which I don't understand because it is defined.

And my question is: will the parameters "@RepairID" and "@NewDetails" get automatically passed to the "UpdateRepairDetails" procedure.  If not, what is the proper approach to accomplish this?

Comment: It says `@NewDetails` is not a scalar variable, not that it is undefined. Is `NewDetails` a table type?

Comment: @Andomar  The sentence below the code answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign NULL to a table variable. Hence you can't check whether a table variable is NULL.

Second: no. You should call as follows:

```
EXEC UpdateRepairDetails @RepairID, @NewDetails;
```

Comment: To clarify for OP who is having problems. A table is not null; you need to check for the existence of rows (e.g., if exists (select * from xxx) ,,, ).

Comment: I marked this as the answer but @SMor added a useful comment that completely answers my questions.  Thanks to both.

Comment: @TT. I still can't get this  to work.  I've removed the null checking and implemented your code but I still get that same error message.

Comment: @SezMe That is weird. I am pretty sure that I pointed out the two problems in your procedure and I can't see any more problems. Can you make a new question with the updated code please?

Comment: @TT Well, isn't this embarrassing.  I shut down the server and my PC and went to bed frustrated.  Fired up everything this morning and no longer get the error.  I blame Bill Gates.

Comment: @TT Well, isn't this even more embarrassing.  The error is back.  I'll start a new quesiton.

Comment: @SezMe Drop a link to the question here, I'll have a look at the new question as well.

Comment: @TT see here;  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45805242/dont-understand-sql-procedure-error-the-sequel