# Must declare the scalar variable when referencing a table valued parameter

Tags: sql-server, table-variable

This question follows from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45664600/dont-understand-sql-procedure-error).

The following SQL works:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Update_Repair_Details]
    @RepairID BIGINT,
    @NewDetails NewDetails READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DELETE FROM Repair_Details
    WHERE RepairID = @RepairID

    INSERT INTO Repair_Details
        SELECT *, GETDATE()
        FROM @NewDetails
END
```

But since `RepairID` is the first column in the user-defined table type, there is no reason to pass it as an additional parameter.

Thus I wrote:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Update_Repair_Details]
    @NewDetails NewDetails READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DELETE FROM Repair_Details
    WHERE RepairID = @NewDetails.RepairID

    INSERT INTO Repair_Details
        SELECT *, GETDATE()
        FROM @NewDetails
END
```

which causes an error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@NewDetails"

Why does this have the error while the previous version does not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, `@NewDetails` is a table; as such, you can't just do `WHERE RepairID = @NewDetails.RepairID`. You can use `IN`, `EXISTS` or a `JOIN`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Update_Repair_Details]
@NewDetails NewDetails READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DELETE A
    FROM Repair_Details A
    INNER JOIN @NewDetails B
        ON A.RepairID = B.RepairID;

INSERT INTO Repair_Details
SELECT *, GETDATE()
FROM @NewDetails;
END
```

Comment: I'd like to understand this answer better (I'm pretty new to SQL).  Is A a synonym for Repair_Details and B for @NewDetails?  But if I do the substitution, I get the same error as in the OP.  Please explain the roles that A and B play.

Comment: I just read that  "When you use a table-valued parameter with a JOIN in a FROM clause, you must also alias it,..." so A and B serve the role of alias, which is required for some reason.

Comment: @SezMe yes, those are table aliases. Are you getting the same error?, that seems weird. Please post the definition of the `NewDetails` type

Comment: No, your correction was right.  Everything is working nowl.